# Automatic timestamp help Google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've started to use Google scripts after using the help desk tutorial to help automate a few things but now I want to go a step further by adding a time stamp whenever the "status" is flipped from a previous status to "Completed".

```
function ClosureTimeStamp(){
var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var active=sheet.getActiveCell()
var date= new Date();
var status= active.getValue();
if(status = "Completed") {(getColIndexByName("Last Status Update")).setValue(date);}
}
```

This is literally the first function I've written and there are bound to be some very basic and glaring errors. I want it so when someone flips over a status to Completed the Last Status Update column for that row drops in a time stamp.

I've had this working with GetLastRow but it wasn't quite doing what I wanted (was updating the last row, not the corresponding row to the status flipped).

```
function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
```

Comment: Please also post your `getColIndexByName()` function you use in your the script here! Even if it the same as this is [one](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/helpdesk_tutorial#section-2-including-ticket-number-and-place-in-the-support-queue-in--the-confirmation-email).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ClosureTimeStamp(){
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var active=sheet.getActiveCell();
  var date=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var status= active.getValue();
  if(status == "Completed"){
    sheet.getRange(active.getRowIndex(),getColIndexByName("Last Status Update")).setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's move it on somewhat but now i'm getting TypeError: Cannot find function setValue in object 19. (line 56, file "Code") (line 56 is the line with the if).

Comment: I looked at the tutorial and getColIndexByName returns an integer not a range so there is no setValue() to an integer.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!